# Localization strings file encoding

Tags: iphone, localization, character-encoding, ios5, nslocalizedstring

I'm about to begin the localization of my App. I've done a test App to check that everything works and, to my pleasure, it does.  I've read that the strings file should be UTF16 encoding for the iOS system however I tested it on my iPhone 4S and it works either with UTF16 or the default UTF8.

Could someboby confirm or deny whether I should use UTF16?

The deployment target is 4.1 though.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use whatever you want, I prefer UTF8 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .strings file is supposed to be UTF-16, according to Apple's specifications. However, the compiler will understand UTF-8 as well.

Comment: Thanks, they shall be UTF16 then.